# nopCommerce 2.3 source code upgrading to nopCommerce 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am working in the nopCommerce 2.30 source code. I create some new Controllers and Views

in the nopCommerce 2.30. Last month i found the new nopCommerce 3.0 version released.

now i trying to upgrade my existing nopCommerce version to new version ( nopCommerce 3.00)

Is any tool available to upgrade the source code 2.30 to 3.00.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a source control tool like TFS with your modified 2.3 as one branch and the new 3.0 as another.  Merge the two branches and use the SQL update scripts provided by NopCommerce.  You'll need one for each version (2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.65, etc).

If all you changed are controllers and views then you can auto-merge the rest and do just those files "by hand" in the merge tool.